# Change background color of a button back after changing it before

Tags: java, android, android-button

I've made an app and now the idea is that the color of a button changes, that already works, but now I'd like to change the color of the button back to the color that is was. Here is my code:

```
if (mQuestionNumber == QuestionLibrary.mQuestionsFrankrijk.length) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivityFrankrijk.this, 
QuizResultaat.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("finalScore", mScoreFrankrijk);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    QuizActivityFrankrijk.this.finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_fout);
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivityFrankrijk.this, "Fout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override

                        public void run() {
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);
                            updateQuestion();

                        }
                    }, 10000);
                    updateQuestion();

                }
```

And the error is that the view of

view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);

is accessed from within inner class and it needs to be declared final, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Simply use a StateListDrawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question directly:

```
    ...
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final View finalView = view;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finalView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);
            updateQuestion();
            ...
```